# Multiple jQuery functions working together

Tags: jquery, document-ready

Is this the correct way to go about using multiple jQuery scripts? Some are in the same .js file, however, even with multiple .js files, it seems that the only way I can get them all to work at the same time is to declare a `jQuery.noConflict()` variable for each of them specifically and then toreplace all the instances of `$` with that variable.

This can't be the correct/best way: isn't it?

I included an example below where all works fine, but this just doesn't seem the 'correct' way to me.

HTML:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="/js/test.js"></script>
<script src="/js/shareit.js"></script>
<script>var $share = jQuery.noConflict();$share(document).ready(function(){$share('.sharer').sharer();});</script>
```

test.js is:

```
/*faq stuff*/
var $zfaqs = jQuery.noConflict();
$zfaqs(document).ready(function () {    
$zfaqs('.faq dd').hide(); // Hide all DDs inside .faqs
$zfaqs('.faq dt').click(function(){$zfaqs(this).toggleClass('active')}); // add/remove active class on click
$zfaqs('.faq dt').click(function(){$zfaqs(this).next().slideToggle('fast')}); // toggle answer
});

/*new window link*/
var $zopen = jQuery.noConflict();
$zopen(document).ready(function() {
$zopen("a[data-window='external']").on('click', function() {
    window.open($zopen(this).attr('href')); 
    return false; 
});
});

/*fading text*/
var $zfader = jQuery.noConflict();
$zfader(document).ready(function(){
$zfader('.fadethis .fade');
    setInterval(function(){
        $zfader('.fadethis .fade').filter(':visible').fadeOut(2000,function(){
            if($zfader(this).next('.fade').size()){
                $zfader(this).next().fadeIn(1000);
            }
            else{
                $zfader('.fadethis .fade').eq(0).fadeIn(1000);
            }
        });
    },10000);   
});
```

EDITED:

Okay, I have changed to the following.  Still a little confused, but I am getting there.  I understand that using the $(document).ready(function() { basically says wait till the page is loaded THEN run through the code - correct?  With that said, I have made the following changes.

In test.js I wrapped all the code within one document.ready and cleaned it up.

What does everyone think now?  Is this now to correct standards?

HTML

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="/js/test.js"></script>

<script src="/js/jquery.colormodal-min.js"></script>
<script>$(document).ready(function(){$("a[data-modal^='gss']").each(function(){$(this).colormodal({rel:$(this).attr('data-modal')});});$("a[data-modal='ss']").colormodal({rel: 'nofollow'});$("a[data-modal='no']").colormodal({title: ' ',rel: 'nofollow'})});</script>

<script src="/js/shareit.js"></script>
<script>$(document).ready(function(){$('.sharer').sharer();});</script>
```

the test.js

```
/*twitter stuff*/
$(document).ready(function() {
$.getJSON('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/testing.json?count=1&callback=?', function(tweets){
$("#twitter").html(tz_format_twitter(tweets));
});

function tz_format_twitter(twitters) {
var statusHTML = [];
for (var i=0; i<twitters.length; i++){
var username = twitters[i].user.screen_name;
var status = twitters[i].text.replace(/((https?|s?ftp|ssh)\:\/\/[^"\s\<\>]*[^.,;'">\:\s\<\>\)\]\!])/g, function(url) {
  return '<a href="'+url+'">'+url+'</a>';
}).replace(/\B@([_a-z0-9]+)/ig, function(reply) {
  return  reply.charAt(0)+'<a href="http://twitter.com/'+reply.substring(1)+'">'+reply.substring(1)+'</a>';
});
statusHTML.push('<span>'+status+'</span> <br/><b><a href="http://twitter.com/'+username+'/statuses/'+twitters[i].id_str+'">'+relative_time(twitters[i].created_at)+'</a></b>');
}
return statusHTML.join('');
}

function relative_time(time_value) {
var values = time_value.split(" ");
time_value = values[1] + " " + values[2] + ", " + values[5] + " " + values[3];
var parsed_date = Date.parse(time_value);
var relative_to = (arguments.length > 1) ? arguments[1] : new Date();
var delta = parseInt((relative_to.getTime() - parsed_date) / 1000);
delta = delta + (relative_to.getTimezoneOffset() * 60);

if (delta < 60) {
return 'less than a minute ago';
} else if(delta < 120) {
return 'about a minute ago';
} else if(delta < (60*60)) {
return (parseInt(delta / 60)).toString() + ' minutes ago';
} else if(delta < (120*60)) {
return 'about an hour ago';
} else if(delta < (24*60*60)) {
return 'about ' + (parseInt(delta / 3600)).toString() + ' hours ago';
} else if(delta < (48*60*60)) {
return '1 day ago';
} else {
return (parseInt(delta / 86400)).toString() + ' days ago';
}
}

/*faq stuff*/   
$('.faq dd').hide(); // Hide all DDs inside .faqs
$('.faq dt').click(function(){$(this).toggleClass('active')}); // add/remove active class on click
$('.faq dt').click(function(){$(this).next().slideToggle('fast')}); // toggle answer

/*new window link*/
$("a[data-window='external']").on('click', function() {
    window.open($(this).attr('href')); 
    return false; 
});

/*fading text*/
setInterval(function(){
    $('.fadethis .fade').filter(':visible').fadeOut(2000,function(){
        if($(this).next('.fade').size()){
            $(this).next().fadeIn(1000);
        }
        else{
            $('.fadethis .fade').eq(0).fadeIn(1000);
        }
    });
},10000);

/*end document ready stuff*/
});
```

Comment: why not call everything in one `.ready`?

Comment: for the functions in test.js I suppose I could, but what if they were all separate .js files?  Isn't there a better way than to use the noconflict on each one?  For sake of ease on my part I usually keep my scripts, especially the longer ones in their own files for easy editing and organization.

Comment: @user756659: `.noconflict()` is for keeping jQuery from conflicting with other libraries that use the `$` global variable. It shouldn't be a problem for you.

Comment: AFAIK, `noConflict` is meant to be used when another lib needs the `$`. If it is still meant to be `jQuery` then you should be able to use `$` no problem.

Comment: I should add that sometimes a script might be only used on a few pages so in that case it would be its own file... yet if I do not use noconflict like I have above then they will not work together.

Comment: is this when there are multiple `$(function(){` in one file or in separate files/locations?

Comment: You don't need `jQuery.noConflict()`, as the others said, unless you *have a potential conflict* such as with MooTools or whatnot which may share the `$` global. What's above seems nonsensical to make a new one for each potential ready block.

Comment: Edited the original with new code.

Answer (score 0):

Try not using `noConflict()` at all, and to not have more than one `$(function(){` per location such as

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $('.sharer').sharer();
  });
</script>
```

and

```
/*faq stuff*/

$(function(){   
  $('.faq dd').hide(); // Hide all DDs inside .faqs
  $('.faq dt').click(function(){$(this).toggleClass('active')}); // add/remove active class on click
  $('.faq dt').click(function(){$s(this).next().slideToggle('fast')}); // toggle answer


  /*new window link*/

  $("a[data-window='external']").on('click', function() {
    window.open($(this).attr('href')); 
    return false; 
  });


  /*fading text*/
  $('.fadethis .fade');  //(not sure what the purpose of this line is)
  setInterval(function(){
    $('.fadethis .fade').filter(':visible').fadeOut(2000,function(){
      if($(this).next('.fade').size()){
        $(this).next().fadeIn(1000);
      }
      else{
        $('.fadethis .fade').eq(0).fadeIn(1000);
      }
    });
  },10000); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider:

```
console.log($); // Will be defined as a jQuery() shorthand
jQuery.noConflict();
console.log($); // Will be undefined
```

What happens is that jQuery will automatically "take" the `$` function shorthand from the global scope, ie, `window.$` will become shorthand for `window.jQuery`.

So, when we call `jQuery.noConflict()` we are *primarily* **releasing** `window.$` back to the wild, in case it conflicts with another framework or library which also uses it (there are several others, MooTools is one).

So the following:

```
var $zfaqs = jQuery.noConflict();
$zfaqs(document).ready(function () { 
    ...
});

var $zopen = jQuery.noConflict();
$zopen(document).ready(function() {
    ...
});

var $zfader = jQuery.noConflict();
$zfader(document).ready(function(){
    ...
});
```

You're simply releasing (over and over) `$` and then creating a *new* global reference to `jQuery` to use within that block that follows. `$zfaqs` should work every time. Unless they are included in a different order each time or whatnot.

As far as what your code is attempting to do, you could accomplish it without the global returned reference to `jQuery` that `jQuery.noConflict()` returns. For instance:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#jQuery-ready').click(function () {
        console.log(this.id);
    });
});

jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#jQuery-only').click(function () {
        console.log(this.id);
    });
});

(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('#Function-initializer').click(function () {
            console.log(this.id);
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/D6ANv/1

And I do not have to do anything like `var $jjq = jQuery.noConflict()` *globally* and then reference those within my `onDOMReady` handlers, I can simply continue to use `$` shorthand within those scopes, as long as I am not then trying to use another global `$` that is not jQuery.